# Android Kotlin: Error when using 'suspend' in DAO - Following CodeLabs guide

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have been following this guide by CodeLabs and on [this section](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4) it shows using the 'suspend' keyword in the DAO methods but when I do it I get this error:

```
error: To use Coroutine features, you must add `ktx` artifact from Room as a dependency. androidx.room:room-ktx:<version>
    public abstract java.lang.Object deleteAll(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public abstract java.lang.Object insert(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^
```

I checked online but people are saying that you can't use coroutines in with DAO methods.

I also added all the build.gradle imports that come before this step [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2).

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I found out what was the issue. Even though I added the coroutine files to the build.grade files, I needed to add Room's specific coroutines file as well which is:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
```

This would be to use coroutines with DAO methods.

I was confused as I thought I added all the necessary files in the previous step.

Comment: In my case I needed to update the version of this lib.

Answer (score 0):

The issue started after migration from `Groovy` to `Kotlin DSL`.

I have tried many combinations between Kotlin, Room, and Coroutines versions, but it didn't help.

My workaround was to upgrade Room to the latest beta version, `2.6.0-beta01`.

Upgrading to beta was not anything critical in my case, but I would not recommend it for some production fixes.